# Probability with binomial and exponential distributions

Tags: probability, statistics

If you are given a questions asking for a probability P(x>1.5), if I calculate using the complement of this probability is it 1-P(x=0)+p(x=1)? Or do i include P(x=2)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working on $\mathbb{R}$ the complement of $\left\{ X>1.5\right\} $ is:

$\left\{ X\leq1.5\right\} $

leading to:

$P\left\{ X>1.5\right\} =1-P\left\{ X\leq1.5\right\} $.

Working on the set of non-negative integers the complement of $\left\{ X>1.5\right\} $ is:

$\left\{ X=0\vee X=1\right\} =\left\{ X=0\right\} \cup\left\{ X=1\right\} $

leading to:

$P\left\{ X>1.5\right\} =1-P\left\{ X=0\right\} -P\left\{ X=1\right\} $.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the Binomial distribution you could do 1-P(0)-P(1).  The Exponential distribution, on the other hand is a continuous distribution, so you can't just use "0" and "1".  To use the complement you would have to do 1-CDF(1.5), where CDF is the cumulative distribution function.

Comment: I'm given a moment generating function of M(t)=[1/(1-t/2)][1/3+2/3e^t]^4, which consists of the exponential and binomial distribution; so I'm not sure how to calculate the probability.

Comment: Do you know the form of the distribution that leads to that MGF?